# Assistance to save USERS and AspNetUser at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Help please. I lost all my day redoing various parts of the system, trying a lot of different solutions but I ended up with no ideas.

I have a solution with same applications. In one of these applications (where I try isolate data persistence) I have context created with DataBase First method in Entity Framework. Note: I had already included in the database, with a create script, the Identity tables.

In another layer of my solution I added a pure MVC application without user control. So I added by nuget, Entity Framework and Identity.

And finally I created ApplicationUser, IdentityDbContext and ApplicationRoleManager:

```
public partial class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Display(Name = "Usuario", Description = "Identificação para Login")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "000027 - O Login não pode ser vazio ou nulo.")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "000028 - O Login pode ter no máximo 30 caracteres.")]
    [DuplicadoNaBase("AspNetUsersDao", "SelecionarPorLogin", ErrorMessage = "000031 - O Login informado já existe na base de dados.")]
    public string LOGIN { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Senha", Description = "Senha para Login")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "000029 - A senha não pode ser vazia ou nula.")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "000030 - A senha pode ter no máximo 30 caracteres.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string SENHA { get; set; }

    public virtual USUARIOS USUARIOS { get; set;}

    [NotMapped]
    public string Perfil { get; set; }
}

public class GPSdEntitiesIdentity :  IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public GPSdEntitiesIdentity() : base("IdentityConnection")
    {
    }
}
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole, string>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new GPSdEntities()));
    }
}
```

Well basically my problem happens because I already had a database with a USER table. Initially I tried to merge my USER table with AspNetUser. But it did not work because AspNetUser has that GUID (string Id) and I would have to redo a lot of relationships in the database. So I kept the two tables. I added an IdAspNetUser to my USERS table and they got a 1 to 1 relationship.

I made a View that works with ApplpicationUser to register user and it was working ok. But I thought it was strange, because I had that I was doing 1 userManager.add and then 1 ContextPerformance.USUARIOS.Add. As the relationship between them is 1 to 1, then I had the brilliant idea of ​​adding in the ApplicationUser a virtual property USERS USERS {get; set} and that's when I started to have mistakes and lap times.

When I try:

```
private UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new GPSdEntitiesIdentity()));
List<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers = new List<ApplicationUser>();
ApplicationUsers = userManager.Users.ToList();
```

I am getting the following error:

> *System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException "One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   GPSd.Web.MVC.IdentityContext.AspNetUserLogins:: EntityType
>   'AspNetUserLogins' has no key defined. Set the key for this
>   EntityType. AspNetUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'AspNetUserLogins'
>   is based on type 'AspNetUserLogins' that has no keys defined.*"

If I mark the USERS Virtual property within ApplicationUser as [NotMapped], the application works again, but then I have to save AspNetId and USER separately

I'm trying to do something simple like this:

```
ApplicationUser identityUser = new ApplicationUser
{
   UserName = model.LOGIN,
   LOGIN = model.LOGIN,
   SENHA = model.SENHA,
   USERS = model.USERS
};
IdentityResult resultado = userManager.Create(identityUser, model.SENHA);
```

Comment: do you have 2 separate contexts? one contains the `AspNetUserLogins` and the other one contains `Users`?, if so u need to add the mapping to your `AspNetUserLogins` in the other context that contains the `Users` and your work should be ok then.

Comment: @Monah Yes is 2 contexto 1 general and other to Identity. Then I need override the OnModelCreating to add aspnetTables and USERS in the IdentityContext? yes... its make sence... Thanks I try do this.

Comment: it is enough to add `modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserLogins>().HasKey(t=>t.Id);` the other mapping is not required since it is already defined in the first context.

Answer (score 0):

In Your `GPSdEntitiesIdentity` add :

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

      modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()
            .HasKey(l => new { l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey, l.UserId })
            .ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");// Database Table Name   

    }
```